# Перенос sql в телеграм

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

Учусь sql3 (точнее основам). Решил перенести данный код в телеграмм (использую TelegramBotApi) В итоге, хотелось бы знать, как можно изменить `input`, ну, это ведь телеграмм, тут не нужна повторная авторизация. Нужно вставить `chat.id`?

```
import sqlite3
from random import randint

global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cu = db.cursor()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
#логин пароль убрал
    win INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()

user_login = input('Ваше имя:') #Тот самый input
password_login = input('Ваш пароль:')
cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
if cu.fetchone() is None:
    cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0, 0))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI ?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @RomanKonoval изменено

Comment: Никогда не вставляйте данные, которые вы не контроллируете (например результат ввода пользователем, или если уж на то пошло  то и chat.id, чем-бы это ни было) непосредственно в SQL команду. Используйте параметры. Иначе когда придет что-нибудь типа "fake login' or '1' = '1", то выполнится совсем не та команда, на которую вы рассчитывали.

Comment: @FiolDoll все равно не ясно о чем вы хотите спросить. Вопрос про то, как реализовать аналог `input` в телеграм? Если так то sql тут лишний. Если же вопрос про sql, то не нужно примешивать сюда `input`. Боюсь, что трудно дать канонический ответ на плохо сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Верно, нужно реализовать input в телеграмм. Если убрать Sql, разве всё не будет сохранятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставить нужно `from_user.id`, потому что у каждого пользователя идентификатор индивидуальный.

**Пример кода**:

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

# Подключаемся к Базе Данных
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cu = db.cursor()

# Создаём таблицу если она ещё не создана
cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    win INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()

# Создаём функцию, которая срабатывает при любом входящем сообщении
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    # Если пользователя в БД нету
    cu.execute(f"SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        # Сохраняем его ID в БД
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 0, 0))
        db.commit()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно зарегистрировал тебя в Базе Данных!')

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python\import telebot.py", line 31, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 536, in __threaded_polling
  self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
    raise self.exception_info
  File "python\import telebot.py", line 22, in echo_all
    cu.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}")
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 1168 and this is thread id 5932.

Comment: @FiolDoll Перепишите 'db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')' на  'db = sqlite3.connect('server.db', check_same_thread=False)'. Должно помочь.

Comment: @FiolDoll немного изменил код, теперь всё должно работать.